# Getting HTML documents from google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have authenticated a user, and I have access to the `Drive API Service Instance` for that particular user. Using the method below, I can get access to all the files:

```
def retrieve_all_files(service):
    """Retrieve a list of File resources.

    Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    Returns:
    List of File resources.
    """

    result = []
    page_token = None

    while True:
        try:
            param = {}
            if page_token:
                param['pageToken'] = page_token
            files = service.files().list(**param).execute()

            result.extend(files['items'])
            page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
            if not page_token:
                break
        except errors.HttpError, error:
            print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
            break

    return result
```

Now, what I want, is that for each of these files, I want to download the HTML versions. Note, that I am only interested in the HTML files. How can I generate links to the HTML zip files, through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the `result`, which is a list of `file` objects (actually, those are dictionaries).

Each one of those objects will have an `exportLinks` property, which is a dictionary itself. Look for a `text/html` key in there (note that it might very well not exist, which would indicate you can't retrieve this file as HTML).

This will be the URL where you can retrieve the file as an HTML export.

---

The detailed reference is documented here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: So, Ideally, `file_object['exportLinks']['text/html']`

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Yes, but you'll have to catch `KeyError` as that link may not be there.